# Необходимо обращаться к Ms sql через веб сервер IIS используя Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sql-server, iis

Я начинающий разработчик приложений под андроид. Вопрос знатокам : 
Можно ли через веб сервер ISS получить доступ к MS SQL 2014, приложение пишется на JAVA среда Android Studio?Если да то каким образом?
Вот код напрямую связанную с БД :

```
package com.example.user.hello;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public  class db_class extends Application{

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   static Connection ConnectionDB() {
        String url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://WIN-H2IOJKV9R76:1433:/Test;";
        String username="khiki";
        String password="12345";

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        java.sql.Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("error from SQL",se.getMessage());
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Error from Class",e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error from Exception",ex.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как в вашем понимании связаны IIS и MS SQL Server? Это ж разные продукты...

Comment: IIS видимо имеет коннект в SQL серверу и играет по сути роль сервера приложений

Comment: Да Barmaley, именно. Как можно это все реализовать )?

Comment: Берете ASP в руки и пишете веб сервис, который на запросы отвечает JSON'ами :)

Comment: Задайте в форуме шарпистам (правильный) вопрос, как написать веб сервис - шарпистов здесь много - уверен, ответят.

Comment: Спасибо Barmaley :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для мобильных устройств соединение с удаленной БД через JDBC является антипаттерном. Ну то есть при наличии правильного JDBC драйвера (то есть, написанного либо на чистом Java или же с поддержкой архитектуры девайса - типа ARM) коннект установить можно и даже можно получить `ResultSet` на свои запросы, но цена такого коннекта будет чрезвычайно высокой: ненадежность соединения, требования к портам девайса, требования к ширине полосы коннекта и проч. - все это обнулит ваши усилия.

Нормальным паттерном является поднятие на стороне сервера [Restful веб сервиса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), который отвечает на запросы JSON/XML данными.

Гуглевская лекция как с этим работать [валяется здесь](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2dn_3573C3RdlVpU2JBWXdSb3c/edit)

В вашем случае, вам нужно написать на стороне IIS небольшой веб сервис, который организует JSON ответы на запросы от Android клиента.